# Is careers for payers different than careers for invitees?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Is careers for payers different than careers for invitees?  Since I already "bought" my place there, would I gain any benefit from being "invited"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one-size-fits-all, official, final, and in all perpetuity throughout the universe answer is that there's no difference.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not the definitive source for this matter, but [the blog states](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/):

> By the way, if you paid in the past: thank you! Your account is free for life. But if you don’t think it was worth it, just email us for a full refund.

That sounds to me like: there's no difference?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.  They were migrated over to the same free service invitees will have access to.

Answer (score 2):

On another note, it'd be really nice if they would at least recognize the 'early adopters' that paid. I get that it's all free now, but some recognition would be nice.

Comment: *squints* Hey, look, is that... is that George Stocker??

Comment: @mmyers yes! He is the one who payed!

Comment: Meh.  I paid too, but I did so knowing that it was quite possible the service would go away or change significantly as time progressed.  I don't feel comfortable asking for my money back, but I can't think of a way for them to recognize early adopters that would actually be meaningful.  It doesn't matter though - the system is ever evolving into a typical jobs board (free to look for job, free to list resume, pay to find and communicate with candidates) as far as where the money comes from.  I think the real value lies in the tie-in with stackoverflow answers/reputation.